# Is it possible to add a HMAC key using Docusign REST API for use in Envelope level webhooks

Tags: docusignapi, webhooks, hmac, docusignconnect

I am able to create a CustomConfiguration using the Docusign Rest API. However, the HMAC keys are generated online using the admin account. Is there a REST API option to add one HMAC key to the users account for use in Envelope level eventNotification Webhooks? There is no option to specify a HMAC key while creating the document (as part of the eventNotification) which will then be used for validating the webhook.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do an HMAC validation per-envelope (part of eventNotification). At this time the only way to use HMAC validation is using an account-wide Connect continuation and that does require administrative access.